# WinUI3 EntryPointNotFoundException After VS 17.1.2 Update

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2022, winui-3

I just installed Visual Studio 2022 17.2.1 and my WinUI3 Project does not run anymore.

Even the installed app on my computer doesn't open.
When I try to compile and run within VS the follow error is generated

> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Unable to find an entry point
> named 'XamlCheckProcessRequirements' in DLL 'Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll'.'

[image: Error]

if dotnet build
[image: dotnet build command]

- I tried to reinstall Visual Studio
- Use Preview Version 17.3
- Try solutions on this thread https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/1762

Answer (score 1):

After the update...the Microsoft.Ui.Xaml nuget package was causing the error.
Removing it solved to problem.
`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.UI.Xaml" Version="2.7.1"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Delete the version of your `Microsoft.ui.xaml` in this path and try to run your project. This solution worked for me

C:\Users\UserName\.nuget\packages\microsoft.ui.xaml

Comment: I recently made a few changes to my project. Not sure which change broke it and caused this same error, but among the changes was updating Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK from 1.0.2 to version 1.4.231115000. Deleting the folder described here fixed it for me.

Comment: I determined my issue was caused by a NuGet package I added, which had in turn listed the `Microsoft.ui.xaml` package as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem. I believe, I could fix the problem by creating the  WinUI3 project using the correct project template.

Before, I used the "Windows App SDK extension" in Visual Studio 2022. Then I removed this extension and instead installed the item "Windows APP SDK C# Templates" from the Visual Studio installer (item from "Installation details").

With the new / correct project template "Empty App, packaged (WinUI 3 in Desktop), I created a WinUI 3 project.

Here you find the relevant parts of the .cjproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <RootNamespace>MyApp</RootNamespace>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
    <Platforms>x86;x64;arm64</Platforms>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <PublishProfile>win10-$(Platform).pubxml</PublishProfile>
    <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
    <EnablePreviewMsixTooling>true</EnablePreviewMsixTooling>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools" Version="10.0.22621.1" />
    <Manifest Include="$(ApplicationManifest)" />
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

You can see, that two Nuget Packages are required:

`Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK` and `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools`.

As you see, I used Windows App SDK 1.1.2 at that time. (I you publish an unpackaged app, the respective Window App SDK needs to be installed on the system, i can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/downloads))

In the project settings, take a look at the value in `TargetFramework` value. It seems that a value of simply "net6.0" does not work. In [this](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4591#issuecomment-971590180) post you will find this statement:

> Changing net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0
> to net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0
> worked for me, too.