# WinUI3 Error: System.EntryPointNotFoundException with Version 17.6.0 of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package, winui-3

I have encountered the following error when I try to run my WinUI3 project.

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Unable to find an entry point named 'XamlCheckProcessRequirements' in DLL 'Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll'.'
```

Specifically, the run options I am using are "Release" "X64" "MyAppName (Package)" "Local Machine". I am using Version 17.6.0 of Visual Studio, and this problem started when I changed my configuration from "Release" to "Debug" (I tried changing it back but this made no difference).

I have tried the solutions suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72324559/winui3-entrypointnotfoundexception-after-vs-17-1-2-update).

Specifically, these were deleting the following folder: C:\Users\UserName.nuget\packages\microsoft.ui.xaml

And ensuring my .csproj (and wapproj) files contains the correct elements.

However, the error persists. If anyone has any suggestions for any other actions to try, I would greatly appreciate if you would please let me know.

Comment: For some reason, your process is using an old version of Microsoft.Ui.Xaml.dll. Make sure you have installed the latest WinAppSDK 1.3 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/stable-channel). Use "procmon" tool from sysinternals or "process hacker 2" tool to determine the path of the dll your process is using loading. On my PC, it's `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.3_3000.851.1712.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll` and it does exports XamlCheckProcessRequirements

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, I updated my WinAppSDK installation to 1.3, did a restart, started procmon, then ran my package. This showed that the dll was successfully loaded from the following folder: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.8_8.2305.5001.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Microsoft.UI.Xaml 
However, when I checked this folder it was empty. However, another entry showed it was successfully loaded from: "C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll" I checked, and this one indeed existed. Please would you let me know if you have any advice for how to proceed from here?

Comment: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll is UWP (provided by Windows), Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll is WinUI3 (provided by WinApp SDK). There are similar "in spirit" (based on same internal Microsoft source code), but totally different as binary files. Not sure what your trying to do, you should provide a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Oh you're right, I didn't realise I had looked up the location of Windows.UI.Xaml.dll rather than Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll. On further inspection, the location was: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.8_8.2305.5001.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe 
I inspected the version of the file, which was 2.8.2305.5001. This conflicted with my NuGet Package manager version, which was 2.8.4. Consequently I tried "upgrading" my NuGet Package version to 2.8.2, however the error persisted. Would you have any other thoughts about where to go from here?

Comment: To answer your questions, my hope is to get my app working again. Which it was, before I switched from "Release" to "Debug" mode and encountered this issue (I tried switching back but this did not fix the issue). As for a reproducible example, I would be happy to do so, but am not sure if it is possible in this case. As the issue is likely caused by various files and settings within my project and I do not know what these are. But if you are able to advise me which files to upload I would be happy to do so.

Comment: The error clearly comes from the fact you're using `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.8_8.2305.5001.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll` (which doesn't export XamlCheckProcessRequirements ) instead of `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.3_3000.851.1712.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll` probably an issue with the .csproj or .vcxproj. You should post what you can somewhere, or start a new project and compare.

Comment: Thank you for this reply, based on this I started a new project, using the "Blank App, Packaged with Windows Application Packaging Project (WinUI3 in Desktop)" template. This worked when I ran the blank app. Then, I used NuGet package manager to add the Microsoft.UI.Xaml version 2.8.4. After I added this, the error reoccurred. I don't see any reference within the csproj file to the folder which it is loading the dll from. I also checked my system path and ensured the folder was not in it. Also, below is the contents of my csproj file (split into two comments due to length restrictions).

Comment: <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <RootNamespace>TestNewApp</RootNamespace>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
    <Platforms>x86;x64;ARM64</Platforms>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

Comment: <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.UI.Xaml" Version="2.8.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.3.230502000" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools" Version="10.0.22621.756" />
    <Manifest Include="$(ApplicationManifest)" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Comment: Ok, so the problem is you manually add  Microsoft.UI.Xaml package which is an old thing. Just don't do that the only references you need are "Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" and "Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools" but just follow the tutorials https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/create-your-first-winui3-app and use Visual Studio's template.

Comment: I deleted the line: <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.UI.Xaml" Version="2.8.4" /> rebuilt my project, and it worked! I don't know why this was automatically included in the default app, whether there is some odd setting that somehow got configured in my Visual Studio, or if this is just badly designed by Microsoft. But either way, thank you so much for your help! If you want to post your reply as an answer, I am happy to mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is for some (probably historical) reason, the [Microsoft.UI.Xaml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.UI.Xaml/) nuget package was added to the project.

This package is a **WinUI 2**, **not WinUI 3** package. It's latest version as of today is 2.8.4.

WinUI 2 is is a library of controls that provides official native Microsoft UI controls and features for Windows *UWP* apps.

But although WinUI 3 is internally based on the same source code as UWP, it's *100% binary incompatible*. So the solution is to simply remove this package and use the standard WinUI3 packages, which are usually setup by Visual Studio-provided [WinUI3 templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/create-your-first-winui3-app).

When using these templates, `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.dll` is implicitly provided by the `Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK` package.